# Mapping a foreign key w/ a different name using Entity Framework Core Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a Product model with a foreign key property called `ProductTypeId`. However, I do not have a `ProductType` model. Instead, I have a `TypeListItem` model. I would like to tell EF to still create a relationship from `ProductTypeId` to the `Id` in `TypeListItem` table.

I would like to use Entity Framework Core fluent API to specify this, but can't figure out how. I believe I used to use `HasRequired`, but I don't think that is available in EF Core.

**Here are the models in question:**

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
}

public class TypeListItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I believe I might need to add a navigation property of `TypeListItem` to the `Product` model to make this possible right?

Comment: Can you post the sample model classes in question?

Comment: @IvanStoev I updated my post to show this.

Answer (score 3):

In EF Core it's possible even without navigation properties, because both `HasXYZ` / `WithXYZ` methods have parameterless overloads (btw, rather than `XYZRequired` / `XYZOptional`, EF Core uses `XYZOne` which can be combined with `IsRequired()`).

The fluent configuration for your model the way it is now is:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasOne<TypeListItem>()
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ProductTypeId);
```